# Find SKU which is related to specific product attribute

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.8

With the following SQL I check on values for a specific attribute:

```
SELECT eav_attribute_option_value.value
FROM eav_attribute_option_value
RIGHT JOIN eav_attribute_option
ON eav_attribute_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id
RIGHT JOIN eav_attribute 
ON eav_attribute_option.attribute_id` = eav_attribute.attribute_id
WHERE eav_attribute.attribute_code = "geb_g"
GROUP BY eav_attribute_option_value.value
ORDER BY eav_attribute_option_value.value ASC
```

Now I need the SKU's related to a value. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You know nobody ever actually used RIGHT JOIN, right?

Comment: @sagi, I thought i placed my question in de right context because of the tags i added to the post (mysql and Magento).  If i knew the table relations, i think i could solve it myself. I will delete my post and repost it with more context.

Comment: @sagi : the OP is right, he is speaking about a know framework with known tables (namely Magento)

Comment: What is the end result your looking for here? You want to get all the products that have a option for a certain attribute right?

Like, if it was the manufacturer attribute you would want to see a list of all the products made by Sony?

Comment: @StevenZurek yes, that's what i'm looking for. We have many custom attributes and now I want to perform some checks because I think i see some wrong data.